# Google calendar list events, output not displayed in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to generate a report to list the current events from a calendar but somehow I don't see the output in google sheets. Can someone please help me with my code below? I have been looking and tweaking but no luck (brain dead ATM)

function listevents(){

```
var ss, range, ui, rcalendarId, ask, askDate, askEnd,cal, start, end, events, num, dateString, eStart,sDate, sTime, string, eEnd, eDate, eTime, data;
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetIDHERE').getSheetByName('SHEETNAMEHERE');
range = ss.getRange(1,1,1,8).setValues([ ["Date Created","Title","Description","Location","Start Date","End Date", "Id", "Creator"] ]);

ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ask = ui.prompt('Search for resource calendar list. Enter the resource calendar id');

askDate = ui.prompt('Enter the Start Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');
start = new Date(askDate.getResponseText());
askEnd = ui.prompt('Enter the End Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');

end = new Date (askEnd.getResponseText()); 
cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ask.getResponseText());

events = cal.getEvents(start,end); 
num = events.length;

for (var i = 0; i < num; i ++) {

// Column: Start Date
eStart = events[i].getStartTime();
sDate = eStart.toDateString();
sTime = sDate.toTimeString();
// Column: End Date
eEnd = events[i].getEndTime();
eDate = eEnd.toDateString();
eTime = eDate.toTimeString();
ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues[ [events[i].getDateCreated(),
                                events[i].getTitle(),
                                events[i].getDescription(),
                                events[i].getLocation(),
                                sDate + " " + sTime,
                                eDate + " " + eTime,
                                events[i].getId(),
                                events[i].getCreators()] ];
```

}
}

I expect the values to be posted in google sheets.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @ Tanaike, I apologize I've been busy lately. I actually did see the missing () in .setValues and added it. However, I still do not see the output posted in Excel sheet. It takes the response from the ui.prompt but I don't see the results in google sheets.

Comment: My goal is to gather a calendar event based on a specified dates for example: Calendar1 with date range = June 1, 2019 - June 31, 2019 and the results should be posted in Google Sheets. We are seeing duplicate meetings sometimes. So, by having this type of script will help us prevent it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I have questions. 1. About `` I still do not see the output posted in Excel sheet.``, can you provide your current script for completely replicating your current issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. 2. About ``My goal is to gather a calendar event based on a specified dates``, I cannot see about this in your question. So can you update your question by including more information? From these information, I would like to confirm and think of your solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Here is my test file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p8VOhUD4agzq_seWWWiIYn658zBh1ZY4a2n_OFu5An4/edit#gid=0

Comment: I tried testing it again but still the same, I only see the header values being posted but it does not display the calendar events in the google sheets. I did another test and removed the end date, it seems ok...I am just not sure if I missed something here. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the Spreadsheet. I found a bound script in the Spreadsheet. You tested the script and you got the issue of ``I tried testing it again but still the same, I only see the header values being posted but it does not display the calendar events in the google sheets.``. If my understanding is correct, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Because my modification points are not reflected to the script which was used for testing. In order to reflect my modification points to your script, please modify as follows.

Comment: 1. Please modify ``sTime = sDate.toTimeString()`` to ``sTime = eStart.toTimeString();`` 2. Please modify ``eTime = eDate.toTimeString();`` to ``eTime = eEnd.toTimeString();``. If other error occurred after these modification, can you provide the detail information for completely replicating the issue? By this, I would like to modify the issue.

Comment: I modified the script, see the above link for the bound script. 
Go in the sheet, click > Scripts - List Events, enter calendar Id: eq0t98up4uo4oe6cqsue2l4ki0@group.calendar.google.com, enter start date - June 22, 2019 and end date June 23, 2019. It should produced 6 events (3 on each dates) but the events are not displayed sheets as it should be. I only see the headers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could that the modified script worked. So can you confirm the following points? 1. Is the calendar yours? 2. Are there some events from June 22, 2019 to June 23, 2019? 3. Can you provide the latest script you tested?

Comment: No worries. I am also trying to think in my end if I missed anything. Yes, the calendar is mine. It is a dummy calendar and also the calendar events I created it for this purpose. You should be able to view the current script as it is bound into the Google Sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I saw your current script from the shared Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the modification points are not correctly reflected. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So I added the whole script I tested in my answer. I could confirm the this script worked. Using this, can you test it again? At that time, please confirm whether there are some events in the inputted dates before. Even if the script didn't work in your environment, I have to apologize again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

1. Please use `toTimeString()` to the date object.
2. In your script, `setValues[ [events[i].getDateCreated(),,,` of `ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues[ [events[i].getDateCreated(),,,` is required to be modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
eStart = events[i].getStartTime();
sDate = eStart.toDateString();
sTime = sDate.toTimeString();
// Column: End Date
eEnd = events[i].getEndTime();
eDate = eEnd.toDateString();
eTime = eDate.toTimeString();
ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues[ [events[i].getDateCreated(),
                                events[i].getTitle(),
                                events[i].getDescription(),
                                events[i].getLocation(),
                                sDate + " " + sTime,
                                eDate + " " + eTime,
                                events[i].getId(),
                                events[i].getCreators()] ];
```

To:

```
var eStart = events[i].getStartTime();
var sDate = eStart.toDateString();
var sTime = eStart.toTimeString(); // Modified
    // Column: End Date
var eEnd = events[i].getEndTime();
var eDate = eEnd.toDateString();
var eTime = eEnd.toTimeString(); // Modified
ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues([ [events[i].getDateCreated(), // Modified
                                events[i].getTitle(),
                                events[i].getDescription(),
                                events[i].getLocation(),
                                sDate + " " + sTime,
                                eDate + " " + eTime,
                                events[i].getId(),
                                events[i].getCreators()] ]); // Modified
```

Or, I think that you can also use `toString()` as follows.

```
var eStart = events[i].getStartTime();
var sDate = eStart.toString(); // Modified
var eEnd = events[i].getEndTime();
var eDate = eEnd.toString(); // Modified
ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues([ [events[i].getDateCreated(),
                                events[i].getTitle(),
                                events[i].getDescription(),
                                events[i].getLocation(),
                                sDate, // Modified
                                eDate, // Modified
                                events[i].getId(),
                                events[i].getCreators()] ]);
```

#### References:

- [toDate​String()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)
- [toTime​String()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

### Edit:

The following sample script is the script I tested. In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. When you use this, please check the Spreadsheet ID.

```
function listEvents(){
  var ss, range, ui, rcalendarId, ask, askDate, askEnd,cal, start, end, events, num, dateString, eStart,sDate, sTime, string, eEnd, eDate, eTime, data;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1p8VOhUD4agzq_seWWWiIYn658zBh1ZY4a2n_OFu5An4').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ss.clear();  
  range = ss.getRange(1,1,1,8).setValues([ ["Date Created","Title","Description","Location","Start Date","End Date", "Id", "Creator"] ]);

    //ASK FOR CALENDAR ID
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ask = ui.prompt('Search for resource calendar list. Enter the resource calendar id');
  cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ask.getResponseText());

    //ASK FOR START DATE CALENDAR SEARCH  -- enter June 22, 2019
  askDate = ui.prompt('Enter the Start Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');
  start = new Date(askDate.getResponseText());
    //ASL FOR END DATE CALENDAR SEARCH  -- enter June 23, 2019
  askEnd = ui.prompt('Enter the End Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');
  end = new Date (askEnd.getResponseText()); 

  events = cal.getEvents(start, end);
  num = events.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    // Column: Start Date
    eStart = events[i].getStartTime();
    sDate = eStart.toDateString();
    sTime = eStart.toTimeString(); // Modified sTime = sDate.toTimeString();
    // Column: End Date
    eEnd = events[i].getEndTime();
    eDate = eEnd.toDateString();
    eTime = eEnd.toTimeString(); // Modified eTime = eDate.toTimeString();

    // DISPLAY RESULT IN SPREADSHEET
    ss.getRange(i+2,1,1,8).setValues([ [events[i].getDateCreated(),
                                        events[i].getTitle(),
                                        events[i].getDescription(),
                                        events[i].getLocation(),
                                        sDate + " " + sTime,
                                        eDate + " " + eTime,
                                        events[i].getId(),
                                      events[i].getCreators()] ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tanaike, thank you so much for looking into this. I tweaked the code a little bit and now it is working. 

The line [ sTime = eStart.toTimeString(); // Modified sTime = sDate.toTimeString()] and eTime = eEnd.toTimeString(); // Modified eTime = eDate.toTimeString(); ] --- I changed it to eTime = eStart.toTimeString(); and eTime = eEnd.toTimeString(); and it worked. I also tweak the code a little, see below.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested or might be able to help retrieving your own Calendar Events, here is the code:

```
function onOpen(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
options = [
{name:"MENU NAME1",functionName:"YOUR FUNCTION NAME HERE"}
];
ss.addMenu("CUSTOM NAME", options);
}

function calEvents(){
var ss, sheet,range, ui, rcalendarId, ask, askDate,askEnd,cal, start, end, events, num, output, startTime,startDate, startTime1, endTime, endDate, endTime1, dataRow;
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('GOOGLE SHEET ID HERE');
sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET NAME HERE');
sheet.clear(); 
range = [];
range.push([ "Date Created","Title","Description","Location","Start Date","End Date", "Id", "Creator" ]);

//ENTER CALENDAR ID HERE
ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ask = ui.prompt('Search for resource calendar list. Enter the resource calendar id');

//ENTER START DATE HERE
askDate = ui.prompt('Enter the Start Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');
start = new Date(askDate.getResponseText());
askEnd = ui.prompt('Enter the End Date. Date must be "Month Date, Year" format (i.e. May 1, 1970)');

end = new Date (askEnd.getResponseText()); 
cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ask.getResponseText());

events = cal.getEvents(start,end); 
num = events.length;

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

// Column: Start Date
startTime = events[i].getStartTime();
startDate = startTime.toDateString();
startTime1 = startTime.toTimeString(); 
// Column: End Date
endTime = events[i].getEndTime();
endDate = endTime.toDateString();
endTime1 = endTime.toTimeString(); 

dataRow = []
dataRow.push(events[i].getDateCreated(),
    events[i].getTitle(),
    events[i].getDescription(),
    events[i].getLocation(),
    startDate + " " + startTime1,
    endDate + " " + endTime1,
    events[i].getId(),
    events[i].getCreators())

range.push(dataRow);
}
sheet.getRange(1,1,range.length, range[0].length).setValues(range);
}
```